# How do I show my android app list in the android market app

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like to show a list of my android apps on clicking a "more apps" link from any of my app. Can anyone please tell me know to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the link which which you have created your app. Not the app name but the Company name or your personal name.
ex.

[See this link](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Outfit%207)

So goto market site, then select your company name and use that link to show your app to other.

Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "market://search?q=pub:YOUR_PUBLISHER_NAME";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I used above code in a click handler. But I am getting below error message. Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW.  can u please tell me how to fix this.